# What are my chances of getting a shiny in my scenario?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I've been breeding a level 82 ditto (not shiny) that i caught myself with a male level 44 french (i heard somewher that the country the pokemon comes from if it was traded matters as well, its also not shiny) espurr that got traded to me. I've been trying to breed them for hours and hours and I'm starting to worry because espurr isn't naitive to the hoenn region (I'm playing alpha sapphire). I'm very aware that shinies don't just happen over night and that I gotta work hard, but I just wanna make sure im actually doing things right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called the **Masuda Method**.

When you breed 2 Pokemon from different languages you increase your odds for obtaining a shiny one. 
The odds to obtain a shiny in Generation VI are 1/4096, and when you use Masuda Method, that odd is multiplied by 6.

So your odds are **6/4096** or **1/683**

Just keep trying, sometimes luck is not on our side.

Comment: Wow, those odds are actually really good! I'll update you when the shiny comes, one day

Comment: Yeah, compared to Gen IV 1/1638 and Gen V 1/1365, odd got really good from Gen VI onwards

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. I was thinking of nicknaming it Rosa if its a girl and Samuel if its a boy